# python pass function with argument to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function that gets two functions as argument and I get an error .

What I have done is created a function named "parent" that takes 2 functions as argument (ux and ui). But ux has arguments too, and it gets them from the parent function:

```
import ID_Ui as Ui


ui = Ui.admin_panel()
# ui returns something like this :
'''Please choose one of the options below : 
Please press 0 if you want to exit the program .
Please press 1 if you want to exit to main menu .
Please press 2 if you want exit to previous section .
Please press 3 if you want to create/modify user account .
Please press 4 if you want to create/modify company account .
Please press 5 if you want to create/modify document type .
Please press 6 if you want to create/modify document ID . '''


def child(*ui):
    user_choice = ui
    if user_choice == 3:
        return 3
    elif user_choice == 4:
        return 4
    elif user_choice == 5:
        return 5
    else:
        return 'error'


def parent(ux, ui):
    user_choice = ui
    x = user_choice
    if user_choice == 0:
        return 0
    elif user_choice == 1:
        return 1
    elif user_choice == 2:
        return 2
    else:
        ux(x)


print(parent(child(), ui))
```

I expect that when I input a number other than [0:2] , it runs the ux function and passes it the x variable as its argument. But I get the following error regarding ux(x) line:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'll assume that the function `menu_conditions` you are invoking is in fact the `parent` function, but I believe you should fix that.

Second, when you run `child()` on the last line, it returns a number, or the string `error`. If you wanted to be able to run `child` inside the `parent` folder, simply pass it without parentheses, like that:

```py
print(parent(child, ui))
```

Comment: yes menu_conditions is parent . sorry for that i wrote it wrong

Comment: i have done as you said . right now i don't get any errors but when i run the function and give it a number, it doesn't return anything .

Comment: If you want to return the output of `ux(x)`, you must specifically say so. change that line to `return ux(x)`

Comment: thank you for you response .i did as you said .the weird thing is now when i pass for example number 5 as input , it returns 'error' which is the last condition of the child function.

Comment: I believe it is because the `child` function receives a star parameter. If you removed that it should work. 
Plus, I'd be really pleased if you marked my answer as correct if it helped you.